# Fourier Transform of an odd function and the Contour Integration

Tags: fourier-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, fourier-transform

I have a question regarding the Fourier transform of an odd function. The function is:

$ \begin{align} 
f(x) = \sin(\eta x)e^{-q|{x}|}, \quad \mathrm{where}\ q,\eta\in\mathbb{R}, q>0.
\end{align}$

So far, I have the following working:

$ \begin{align} 
F(k) &= \int^{\;\infty}_{-\infty} dx\;e^{-ikx}\;\sin({\eta}x)e^{-q|x|} \\
&= \int^{\;0}_{-\infty} dx\;e^{-ikx}\;\sin({\eta}x)e^{qx} + \int^{\infty}_{0} dx\;e^{-ikx}\;\sin({\eta}x)e^{-qx} \\
&= \int^{\;0}_{-\infty} dx\;e^{-ikx}\;\left[\frac{1}{2ix}\left(e^{i\eta x}-e^{-i\eta x}\right)\right]e^{qx} + \int^{\infty}_{0} dx\;e^{-ikx}\;\left[\frac{1}{2ix}\left(e^{i\eta x}-e^{-i\eta x}\right)\right]e^{-qx} \\
&= \frac{1}{2i}\int^{\;0}_{-\infty} dx\;e^{i(-k+\eta)x}\;\frac{e^{qx}}{x}-e^{i(-k-\eta)x}\;\frac{e^{qx}}{x} + 
\frac{1}{2i}\int^{\infty}_{0} dx\;e^{i(-k+\eta)x}\;\frac{e^{-qx}}{x}-e^{i(-k-\eta)x}\;\frac{e^{-qx}}{x} \\
\end{align}$

So my rationale is that because there is a modulus on the $x$, I have to split the domain up. And I get a mess like this. So my question is two-fold:

- Is there a simpler method to compute the Fourier transform in this case, keeping in mind that the function I am working with is odd?
- If not, how would I go about computing the integral? I think I should be using contour integration, by considering the analytic continuation over the complex plane and closing the contour. But down the line, I am wondering if it is possible to use Jordan's Lemma? Since the integration limits are from $0$ to $\infty$ and $-\infty$ to $0$.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a bit simpler than you illustrate.  Let me write the FT as

$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \sin{\eta x} \, e^{-q |x|} \, e^{i k x} &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \sin{\eta x} \, e^{-q |x|} \cos{k x} + i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \sin{\eta x} \, e^{-q |x|}  \sin{k x} \\ &= i \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \sin{\eta x} \, \sin{k x} \,  e^{-q |x|} \\ &= \frac{i}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \left [\cos{(\eta-k) x} - \cos{(\eta+k) x} \right ] \, e^{-q |x|} \\ &= i \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \, \left [\cos{(\eta-k) x} - \cos{(\eta+k) x} \right ] \, e^{-q x} \\ &= i \, \operatorname{Re} \int_{0}^{\infty} dx \, \left [e^{i(\eta-k) x} - e^{i(\eta+k) x} \right ] \, e^{-q x} \\ &= i \operatorname{Re} \left [\frac1{q-i(\eta-k)} - \frac1{q-i(\eta+k)}\right ] \end{align} $$

Therefore,

> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, \sin{\eta x} \, e^{-q |x|} \, e^{i k x} = i 2 q \left [\frac1{q^2+(k-\eta)^2} - \frac1{q^2+(k+\eta)^2} \right ] $$

Note that contour integration would not have helped as there were no poles in the integrand.  Rather, I just exploited the symmetries of the integrand to extract the simple result provided by this integral.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I want to clarify, isn't the FT for f(x) given by $\int^{-\infty}_{\infty}dx\;f(x)e^{-ikx}$? That is, the exponent should be $-ikx$? Nevertheless, thank you for the general idea. I'll give it another shot

Comment: @TroyG: there are lots of ways to define the FT, depends on the application.  In any case, the negative in the exponent would just change the sign of the answer, nothing else.